# Saving an object created by pushViewport for plotting two of them together

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have created a somewhat esoteric plot. I have some data which are 8 factors that have been rated 1-4 and I am interested in the distribution of those ratings for each of those factors. However, there is also spatial information and I would like to reflect that in my plot.

There is a [full code that simulates and generates the first two figures here](https://pastebin.com/92ti0E1X), using this type of code:

```
posi <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
for (k in posi) {
  pushViewport( viewport(x=xpos[k], y=ypos[k], w=.14, h=.2) )
  p <- ggplot(aes(x=1, y=proportion, fill=Rating, group=Rating), data=subset(df,class==lev[k]))  +  
    geom_col(show.legend=F) + theme_void() + ggtitle(lev[k])
  p = p + scale_fill_grey(start = .9, end = .0)
  g <- ggplotGrob(p)
  grid.draw(g)
  popViewport()}
```

Creates this plot type:

[image]

Ideally, I would like to plot two of those next to each other like this:

[image]

….but I have not had luck with saving it as a single object such as plot1. If so it should be possible to for instance do something like:

```
ggdraw(plot_grid(plot_grid(plot1, plot2, ncol=2, align='v')
```

How would you go about plotting these different types together? Or alternatively display this data in another fashion that can be more easily saved. 
Thank you for taking time to read my question and I hope that you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't quite grasp the question earlier, but here is a solution that worked for me. We start at the part of your code that makes the plots and then call `grid.grab()` to capture the currently displayed things.

```
### Plot 1
posi <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
for (k in posi) {
  pushViewport( viewport(x=xpos[k], y=ypos[k], w=.14, h=.2) )
  p <- ggplot(aes(x=1, y=proportion, fill=Rating, group=Rating), data=subset(df,class==lev[k]))  +  
    geom_col(show.legend=F) + theme_void() + ggtitle(lev[k])
  p = p + scale_fill_grey(start = .9, end = .0)
  g <- ggplotGrob(p)
  grid.draw(g)
  popViewport()}

g1 <- grid.grab(wrap.grobs = TRUE)

# Plot 2
grid.newpage()
posi <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
for (k in posi) {
  pushViewport( viewport(x=xpos[k], y=ypos[k], w=.14, h=.2) )
  p <- ggplot(aes(x=1, y=proportion2, fill=Rating, group=Rating), data=subset(df2,class==lev[k]))  +  
    geom_col(show.legend=F) + theme_void() + ggtitle(lev[k])
  p = p + scale_fill_grey(start = .9, end = .0)
  g <- ggplotGrob(p)
  grid.draw(g)
  popViewport()}

g2 <- grid.grab(wrap.grobs = TRUE)
```

Then we display them side by side and capture it again with `grid.grab()`.

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(1,2)))
g1$vp = viewport(layout.pos.col = 1)
grid.draw(g1)
g2$vp = viewport(layout.pos.col = 2)
grid.draw(g2)

both <- grid.grab(wrap.grobs = TRUE)

grid.newpage(); grid.draw(both)
```

[image: fferen]

Now you have the `both` object that you can use elsewhere in the script.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but the issue is that I cannot assign this object as you do with:

g1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point()

If you can show me how to do that with the object I create in the code above, I would be thankful.

Comment: You are right, I answered too hastily and I've amended the answer. Could you see if the above now works for you?

Comment: That works here and did exactly what I was asking for. Now that I have your attention, do you know an obvious way to add labels and and text to this figure as in my original question? In any case thank you very much for you help, and I think I could figure out that part eventually in any case.

Comment: My best bet would be to use `pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout()))` again with the appropriate widths/heights and use `grid.text()` and the `both` object to fill the correct spots in that layout.